# Delay in loading encrypted local storage on iOS using WL.EncryptedCache.open

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using WL.EncryptedCache.open to open the locat storage. This at times takes 4-8 seconds to get the encryption key. Please suggest on how to resolve this performance issue ? 
We are using Worklight 6.0

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the secure token locally by overwriting the secure random call: `WL.EncryptedCache.secureRandom = function(callback){callback(Math.random()+"")}`. That way you don't have to hit the server to get it. It will be significantly less secure and I do **not** recommend it. Beyond that and running the application on a faster device, there's nothing you can do. Generating a secure key is an expensive operation.

Alternatively, you can replace `Math.random` above with a cordova plugin `exec` call that gets a cryptographically secure random string using [SecRandomCopyBytes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/Reference/reference.html). Some example code:

```
int bytes = 32;

uint8_t randBytes[bytes];

int rc = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, (size_t)bytes, randBytes);

if (rc != 0) {
    //handle failure
}

NSMutableString* hexEncoded  = [NSMutableString new];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
    [hexEncoded appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", randBytes[i]]];
}

NSString* randomStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", hexEncoded];
```

There are getting started modules that explain how to write cordova plugins for iOS [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html).